# NavigationDrawer with ActionBarSupport

Tags: android, android-layout

[This popular guide](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#top) suggests using drawer for post honeycomb devices which aren't yet dominating the overall scene. So, I tried to rewrite the same code with ActionBarSupport from ActionBarActivity.

It doesn't work completely perfect though: ActionBarDrawerToggle isn't rendered properly - there is no icon with 3 stripes, homebutton clicks don't open/close the drawer.

Has anyone tried doing it? And what are the workarounds for ActionBarSupport with NavigationDrawer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a library which works fine.

https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/SherlockNavigationDrawer

Comment: It forces me to use Sherlock. What if I don't want to? I asked about ActionBarSupport not Sherlock

Comment: then, probably you have to implement it on your own. if i find a solution i will keep you posted here.

Comment: not having found anything suitable I switched to Sherlock. Thanks for the library.